# Error finding the difference between two dates in Sybase IQ

Tags: date, sap-iq, sql-date-functions, date-difference

I want to find the difference between a date(in a nvarchar column in the table) and the current date.

I tried using datediff, however I keep getting a 'type conversion fails' message.

FYI, format of date 1 is mm/dd/yyyy
format for date 2(getdate()) is yyyy-mm-dd

Could you tell me a datediff syntax for calculating the difference between the two dates in months

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `date_order` option to 'MDY'. This is the option used to convert a string to a date. If you only want to do this for the current connection, you can use `set temporary option date_order='MDY'`, or you can change the default for your user using `set option date_order='MDY'`.